# Why won't my form submit?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I am trying to make a votting site for my server, and i got everything ready. My only issue is that my form won't submit, why is this? Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Vote For Us!</title>
<style>
body {background-color:gray;}
#Holder {width:220px; height:50px; top:5px; left:5px; background-color:black;  border:3px outset darkred; position:absolute;}
#Holder #Input {top:12px; left:5px; position:absolute;}
#Holder #Submit {top:12px; right:5px; background-color:black; border:2px outset darkred; color:white; position:absolute;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="Holder">
<form method="post" auction="Vote.php">
<input type="text" id="Input" name="Input" />
<input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a typo "auction"

Comment: Why is my question being down voted?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/sx5exs7h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your `form` tag, you have a spelling error. Instead of `auction` you should have `action`.

Answer (score 8):

You used an attribute named `auction` on your `<form>` tag, and I can only assume you wanted to write `action` instead. Change it and it should work.